# mvc3 jquery to change ViewBag Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

**I have 2 if statements that use a ViewBag value that ties it down to a dropdownlist how if a user changes the ViewBag Value can I detect it with Jquery** for instance I have...

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyValue", new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{  
                  new{ Text = "10", Value= 10}, 
                   new{ Text = "30", Value= 30}}, "Value", "Text"))

 @if (ViewBag.MyValue == 10)
 {
    // value is 10
 }
  @if (ViewBag.MyValue == 30)
  {
   // my value is 30
  }
```

As you can see I have a dropdownlist with the **I.D. MyValue** is there some way that i can get Jquery to do something like

```
**MyValue.change 
{
if (MyValue== 30)
{
// display ViewBag.MyValue== 30 
}
}**
```

Comment: Basically, you can not change any `ViewBag` values on client side without calling the server. You should use Jason Evans' answer and modify your page on selectlist change. As an option: create two divs with id="value10" and id="value30" and display them depending on what option was selected. `$("#MyValue").change(function() {
    var selector = "#value" + $(this).val();
    $(selector).show();
});`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$("#MyValue").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```